# Add background blur to a SKSpriteNode (or SKScene)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, overlay, blur, scenekit

I have an **OverlayPanel SKScene** on a **SCNScene**. This panel contains colors as **SKSpriteNode**. I don't know how to add a background blur effect to the panel.

[image: This is the ColorPanel SKScene]

Another question: I use this method to add the panel:

```
 colorPanelScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "art.scnassets/ColorPanelScene")!
 SCNsceneView.overlaySKScene = colorPanelScene
 SCNsceneView.overlaySKScene!.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Is this the correct way or should I create the panel as a **separate UIView** (and apply the blur effect in a simplier way)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an `SKEffectsNode` to your overlay scene to achieve this effect.

It is a little tricky though, loading it the way you are doing it will not be enough.

This method will only work with the background being static. Basically what we are going to do is screen shot the background, and load it into an `SKEffectNode` to get it to blur.

In the SceneKit editor, add a node to the scene(make sure it is not a child of other nodes) and make sure you set the class of this node to be an `SKEffectNode` with a name,  I will call it EffectNode.  This should have the lowest `zPosition` as possible when designing.

Then in code, you want to do the following:

```
if let effectNode = colorPanelScene.childNodeWithName("EffectNode") as? SKEffectNode {
    let  blur = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur",withInputParameters: ["inputRadius": 10.0]);
    effectNode.filter = blur;
    effectNode.shouldRasterize = true;
    effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = true;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let node = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(image: image));
    effectNode.addChild(node);
}
```

Then, add another `SKNode` on top of the `SKEffectNode`, but make sure that it is not a child of the `SKEffectNode`. Throw all of your overlay elements into this `SKNode`.

Comment: in line "let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:image);" xCode said: "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage!' to expected argument type 'String'"

Comment: fixed it, forgot you ha to make a texture

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a `UIVisualEffectView`. It has all the nice optimizations from the UIKit and Core Animation guys, and will make your app look consistent on the platform.

Comment: Do you mean adding more Views? SCNScene + UIView with blur effect?

Comment: yes. A `SCNView`, a `UIVisualEffectView` and a `UIView` or `SKView` for the UI.

Comment: this could be easier, but perhaps it may be less performant. Is that right?

Comment: not necessarily. `UIVisualEffectView` was created exactly for that and was tuned so that it can be used extensively.

Comment: I like this approach, but it does affect performance on sprite kit unfortunately if you have a lot going on,